# How to test method that called new inside himself

Tags: spring-boot-test

Is there any way to test this method, i need to mock FooWrapper and doNothing on wrapper.connect and return some byte[] when call wrapper.retrieveFileBytes(path.replace("somePath", ""))

```
 @Override
    public List<Foo> getFoolList(String path) {
        try (FooWrapper wrapper = new FootWrapper(
                host, port, login, password, logging, connectionTimeOut)
        ) {
            wrapper.connect();
            byte[] archiveBytes = wrapper.retrieveFileBytes(path.replace("somePath", ""));
           //some logic
    }
```

it will be seems like this

```
wrapper = Mockito.mock(FooWrapper.class);
when(wrapper.connect).thenDoNothig;
when(wrapper.retrieveFileBytes(any)).thenReturen(someBytes[]);
```

and test it

```
assertTrue(Foo, getFooList("test").get(o));
```

Comment: FooWrapper implements AutoCloseable, that why i need to use new()

Comment: what do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test this method , first i need to mock wrapper to be able to do mock.connect that will do nothing and wrapper.retriveFileBytes that will return mock byte[], then i check  what this method will return

Comment: and you cannot have another method that receives the byte[] ? and test that directly

Comment: No i cant, this is ftp client with connection and closing resources